# Find $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R^2} - \{ (0,0)\}$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Consider the vector field $X = x \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial }{\partial y} $ on $\mathbb{R^2}$. I need to find a $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R^2} - \{ (0,0)\}$ such that $\omega(X) = 0$.

Here's what I tried:

$$\omega(X) = (a \ dx + b  \ dy) \Big( x \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big) = ax + by = 0.$$

Now, since $a= -y, b=x$ is the solution of above equation, we get the following $1$-form

$$\omega = -y \ dx + x \ dy.$$

But since I need to find $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R^2} - \{ (0,0)\}$ so there are several other values of $a$ and $b$ possible. Like $a= x/y$, $b = -x^2 / y^2 $. So which one I need to consider here?

Comment: You need find **a** form satisfying the conditions. You've found.

Comment: A more interesting question would be to find a nonzero _closed_ 1-form $\omega$ such that $\omega(X) = 0$. In that case, $\omega = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-form $\omega = -y dx + xdy$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ satisfies the condition $\omega(X) = 0$ as would any multiple of $\omega$.

However, the other form you suggested, $\frac{x}{y}dx - \frac{x^2}{y^2}dy$ doesn't work as it is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ (it is undefined whenever $y = 0$).

Comment: Why is it undefined for non-zero $y$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant when $y$ is zero.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese So then, is the second form right?

Comment: @Dark_Knight: The point $(0, 0)$ is excluded, but there are other points in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ with $y = 0$, for example $(1, 0)$.

Comment: oh sorry, a stupid argument. I'll delete it.